# How to show an entity from in the Wirecloud MapViewer widget

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Well I'm trying to show the following entity:

```
{
  "contextResponses" : [
    {
      "contextElement" : {
        "type" : "City",
        "isPattern" : "false",
        "id" : "Miraflores",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "name" : "position",
            "type" : "coords",
            "value" : "-12.119816, -77.028916",
            "metadatas" : [
              {
                "name" : "location",
                "type" : "string",
                "value" : "WSG84"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "statusCode" : {
        "code" : "200",
        "reasonPhrase" : "OK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Wiring NGSI Source and NGSI Entity to Poi operatiors with MapViewer widget (Insert/Update PoI), with the following settings:

### NGSI Source

- **NGSI server URL:**   mydirection:1026
- **NGSI proxy URL:**  http://mashup.lab.fi-ware.org:3000/
- **NGSI entities:** City
- **NGSI Attributes:** position

### NGSI Entity to Poi

- **Coordinates attribute:** position

But nothing shows up in the map! Can somebody help me figure out what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your configuration is correct (I'm assuming mydirection:1026 is a full URL, i.e. includes the protocol), but probably your network is filtering port 3000. Try to use `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org` as NGSI proxy instead of `http://mashup.lab.fi-ware.org:3000/`.

Indeed, I recommend you to [enable https notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338154/orion-context-broker-https-for-subscribers) in your context broker instance and use `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org` instead, especially if you are creating your WireCloud dashboard in an https web page (e.g. https://mashup.lab.fi-ware.org) as using this NGSI proxy will solve some mixed content problems, see:

- **Chrome:** https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en
- **Firefox:** https://blog.mozilla.org/tanvi/2013/04/10/mixed-content-blocking-enabled-in-firefox-23/

**Update**: FIWARE has move from fi-ware.org to fiware.org. The recommended NGSI proxy server is now `ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` (`ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org` still works).

Comment: I was checking all URLs to configure my NGSI proxy and in my system, any is working. What URL proxy is working now?

Comment: @miguelbemartin, the host name (DNS) of the FIWARE Lab's NGSI proxy is `ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`. If your context broker supports https notifications then use `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org`, else use `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` but taking into account the mixed content problems that will arise.

Comment: I don't know what is my error. I safe the position like that:

{
            "name" : "position",
            "type" : "coords",
            "value" : "40.4, -3.6833",
            "metadatas" : [
              {
                "name" : "location",
                "type" : "string",
                "value" : "WGS84"
              }
            ]
          },

Answer (score 1):

Three simple steps to start *MapViewer* on Fiware:

1. Update the *Orion ContextBroker* in your system
2. You should check if the daemons *rush* and *rdis* are installed and running in your system
3. You should create a correct boot sequence in the *init.d*: *redis*, *rush* and *contextBroker*

After these steps, you can build your viewing interface in *Wirecloud* using *MapViewer*, *NGSI source* and *NGSI entity to POI*.

You must use structured JSON messages correctly as in the following example:

```
{ "contextElements": 
 [
    {
        "type": "iotdevice","isPattern": "false","id": "edison1", "attributes": 
        [
            {
                "name": "temperature",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "10"
            },
            {
            "name" : "position",
            "type" : "coords",
            "value" : "-20, 35",
            "metadatas" : [
              {
                "name" : "location",
                "type" : "string",
                "value" : "WSG84"
              }
         ]
         }
]
}
],

   "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

Comment: What is exactly the configuration of the "wiring" boxes? I safe the position like that but I can't show the position in the map.

Comment: What is your Orion version?

Comment: Any answer? I just updated the version of Orion Context Broker to 1.0.0 because the old version was not working.

Comment: You should use Chrome web browser to view the map viewer. I've done tests with other browsers, but only chrome is properly working . This is my wirecloud link: https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/fabiocabrini/teste?mode=embedded&theme=wirecloud.oiltheme