# Rush installation and integration with Orion Context Broker

Tags: https, fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

After having running the listener and one time a consumer in the Rush, I run:

```
contextBroker -rush localhost:5001
```

I made sure to use Orion 0.17 instead of 0.14 and what It's shown after enter to the /version url is:

```
<orion>
<version>0.17.0</version>
<uptime>0 d, 0 h, 12 m, 14 s</uptime>
<git_hash>127793ff921b37a6a570cd315ddce9a3ec541ccf</git_hash>
<compile_time>Fri Nov 28 09:41:22 CET 2014</compile_time>
<compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
<compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

Now Rush relayer works fine, what it's shown in the terminal is :

```
[root@fiware ngsi-proxy]# contextBroker -rush localhost:5001INFO@15:49:27  contextBroker.cpp[1348]: Orion Context Broker is running
[root@fiware ngsi-proxy]# INFO@15:49:27  MongoGlobal.cpp[164]: Successful connection to database
INFO@15:49:27  contextBroker.cpp[1157]: Connected to mongo at localhost:orion
INFO@15:49:28  MongoGlobal.cpp[483]: Database Operation Successful ({ conditions.type: "ONTIMEINTERVAL" })
INFO@15:49:28  contextBroker.cpp[1435]: Startup completed
[root@fiware ngsi-proxy]# INFO@16:01:41  rest.cpp[667]: Starting transaction from 181.64.209.16:8204/version
INFO@16:01:41  rest.cpp[380]: Transaction ended
INFO@16:01:42  rest.cpp[667]: Starting transaction from 181.64.209.16:8204/favicon.ico
WARNING@16:01:42  badRequest.cpp[52]: Bad Input (service '/favicon.ico' not found)
INFO@16:01:42  rest.cpp[380]: Transaction ended
```

Comment: We would need some more information in order to help you. Is there any ERROR message in either Rush consumer logs or Rush listener logs? If there isn’t any, try changing the log level to debug in the lib/configBase.js file and restart both services (something might have gone wrong during initialization). What version of redis did you install? Remember 2.6 at least is required for Rush to work properly. Please edit your question to include that information.

Comment: @fgalan I left the logs you're asking. If any other information is required, please let me know.

Comment: Which redis version are you using? Please, edit your question to include that information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `http://myorionserver:1026` for filling the NGSI Server URL setting as this is the URL for your Orion Context Broker instance. Make sure your orion context broker is accessible from outside by opening the following URL: `http://myorionserver:1026/version`. You should obtain something similar this:

```
<orion>
  <version>0.17.0</version>
  <uptime>0 d, 4 h, 38 m, 48 s</uptime>
  <git_hash>127793ff921b37a6a570cd315ddce9a3ec541ccf</git_hash>
  <compile_time>Fri Nov 28 09:41:22 CET 2014</compile_time>
  <compiled_by>fermin</compiled_by>
  <compiled_in>centollo</compiled_in>
</orion>
```

Check your firewall configuration if you have problems connecting to your orion server. Everything else seems to be ok.

**UPDATE:** After your update, seems that the problem is related to the version of the Orion Context Broker you were using. Rush integration needs at least version 0.14.1, but I recommend you to use at least version 0.17 as this version contains, among other things, important fixes regarding Rush integration. In general is always a good idea to update to the latest stable version of Context Broker ;-)

Comment: It seems that the introduction of libcurl as HTTP sending library in 0.14.1 was a *big* improvement compared with the previous system :)