# mapViewer widget doesn't show map markers

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

Following my previous question [Rush installation and integration with Orion Context Broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318463/rush-installation-and-integration-with-orion-context-broker) I have Rush Relayer working properly, but it still doesn't let me show the markers on the mapViewer.

What I get in my instance is:

```
 INFO@21:01:23  clientSocketHttp.cpp[348]: Notification Successfully Sent to localhost:5001/callbacks/23:01:42-1:23:01:45-1
INFO@21:01:23  clientSocketHttp.cpp[359]: Transaction ended
time=2015-01-14T21:01:23.305Z | lvl=INFO | op=RELAY REQUEST | msg=Relay Request received | corr=N/A | trans=7f1d7e00-9c30-11e4-b26a-090df9e0789f | hostname=fiware | component=listener | userID='127.0.0.1' | reqInfo={ url: '/callbacks/23:01:42-1:23:01:45-1',  method: 'POST',  remoteAddress: '127.0.0.1',  headers:    { 'x-relayer-host': 'ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org:443',     'x-relayer-protocol': 'https',     'x-relayer-proxy': undefined,     'x-relayer-retry': undefined,     'x-relayer-httpcallback': undefined,     'x-relayer-persistence': undefined,     'x-relayer-traceid': undefined,     'x-relayer-encoding': undefined,     'content-type': 'application/xml' },  responseTime: 8,  statusCode: 201,  bodyLength: 3323,  id: { id: '7f1d7e00-9c30-11e4-b26a-090df9e0789f' } }
```

Everything seems to work well but I can't see the markers on the mapViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as it is Rush related, it would be important to have the traces at the Consumer process, there we could see if there is any problem with the relay itself. The listener just tell us that Rush has created a relay task.

Could you please post that traces?

Comment: It's weird that after enter so many times to //mashup.lab.fiware.org/user/Workspace#view=workspace&tab=Tab  , the markers are shown on the mapViewer but I don't know how to avoid waiting so much, because sometimes whenever I go to the page it just doesn't load as easy and It sometimes doesn't load properly keeping its loading percentage in 33% o something like that and never get loaded completely. Is that a problem that I only have?

Comment: after I reload the mashup web it didn't show the markers again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, if the markers reach the map then Rush is working properly (anyway if you could provide the tracelogs maybe we could see if there is any delay involved in the relay of the request). It seems that the problem is widget (FE/BE) related more than Rush.