# Show orion context broker poi in map viewer

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

For learning porpoises I am trying to run the default map viewer set up and show the POIs stored in the orion public instance (orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026).. but it does not work at all.

Following screenshots with the default provided configurations. It should show a bunch of Santander POIs if I understood well.

1.-Wired mashups schema:
[image: 1.-Wired mashups schema]

2.- NGSI Source default settings:
[image: 2.- NGSI Source default settings]

3.- NGSI entity to POI default settings:
[image]

4.- Map viewer default settings:
[image]

5.- Map viewer result (No results at all :(( ):
[image]

Everything looks pretty straight forward but nothing is shown. Without understanding why it is not working I can not moving forward and work in my own implementation.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have not obtained an authorization token (or you are not showing it in your question?). Without one you are not able to retrieve information from orion.lab.fi-ware.org.

One way to get a token is running this python script:
https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-figway/blob/master/python/get_token.py

Of course, you do need a FIWARE Lab account to get it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! :) I am trying to show the POIS from the mashup section inside FIWARE admin panel https://mashup.lab.fiware.org/vicens-1/Workspace#view=workspace which I am properly log in. From there I don't need any token and I won't be able to install it... is FIWARE environment.

Comment: This other question may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129318/how-to-show-an-entity-from-in-the-wirecloud-mapviewer-widget?lq=1

Comment: Thanks I look into this! Anyway this link point how to get data from a orion instance and a custom entity... BUT I don't still know why is not working against your own public system: (http://orion.lab.fi-ware.org:1026/) and with your own entities (Node, AMMS, Regulator). Maybe you should check if the demo provided in Mashup Store (StarterKit) works... looks like not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in the configuration of the "NGSI entity to POI". The `Node`, `AMMS` and `Regulators` entities provide their coordinates using the `Latitud` (latitude) and `Longitud` (longitude) attributes.

The final value for the "Coordinate attribute" setting should be: `Latitud, Longitud`