# Canot see any POI on Wirecloud Map Viewer, using Madrid example

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

im taking my firsts steps, working with mashup wirecloud.
I successfully finished the Santander POI example, could see all the POI on the map viewer, the info on each POI, and the chart info.

Then i proceeded for the Madrid example, in which i had to first create the entity on context broker etc, And this is the one where i am having problems.

My curl request to create entity:

```
    (curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "City",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Madrid",
            "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "position",
                "type": "coords",
                "value": "40.418889, -3.691944",
                "metadatas": [
                    {
                        "name": "location",
                        "type": "string",
                        "value": "WGS84"
                    }
                ]
            }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

I can see that the info is reachable, by using for example the NGSI Browser widget, i can see the entity Madrid of type City, with attributes position, and value of the coords, but cannot see the POI on map viewer.

My Mashup config:

**NGSI Source:**

NGSI server URL: http://130.206.117.220:1026

NGSI proxy URL: https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org

Use the FIWARE credentials of the user: yes

NGSI entity types: City

Monitored NGSI Attributes: position

**NGSI entity to POI:**

Coordinates attribute: position

Before posting this question, i looked over all the similar questions in stack overflow, but none of the answers i saw helped so far.
Thank you in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your instance doesn't support sending notifications to https servers. You can test it by using `http://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org` as value for the `NGSI proxy URL` preference. Probably your browser will complain about mixed content see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129318/how-to-show-an-entity-from-in-the-wirecloud-mapviewer-widget/27132007#27132007) for more info, so I recommend you to install Rush and enable https support in your orion context broker instance.

Take a look into the "Rush relayer" section of the [orion documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/develop/doc/manuals/admin/rush.md) for more info on how to enable https support. Also take a look into the questions and answers available on [Stack Overflow about rush/orion](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfiware-orion%5D+rush).

> **NOTE**: I changed the following preferences for testing so the parameters match the MadridTest entity.
>
> **NGSI Source:**
>
> - NGSI entity types: CityTest
> - Monitored NGSI Attributes: Latitud, Longitud
>
> **NGSI entity to POI:**
>
> - Coordinates attribute: Latitud, Longitud