# How can I use Mashup-Wirecloud Map Viewer from Orion Context Broker?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

My configuration in "wiring view" has the following components:

- **NGSI-source:** Monitored NGSI Attributes: position
- **NGSI Entity to Point:** Coordinates attribute: position

And these boxes are connected to Map Viewer, but I can't see the points in the map. Could you please answer the following questions?

1. Where is the problem?
2. Should I change the name of the attributes?

Comment: Please, provide all the values used to configure the NGSI source operator, provide info about your entities and about your Context Broker instance if you are not using `orion.lab.fiware.org`.

Comment: I'm using mashup.lab.fiware.org

In the Ngsi source:
NGSI server URL: http://MIIP:1026/ (this configuration is working correctly in other part, it is not the error)
NGSI proxy URL: https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org
Credentials of the user: YES
Use the FIWARE credentials of the workspace owner: NO
NGSI tenant/service : 
NGSI scope /
NGSI entity types: Patient (the name of my entity)
Id pattern: false
Monitored NGSI Attributes: position

NGSi entity to PoI
Coordinates attribute: position
Marker Icon

Comment: Please, add all the information you provided in the last comment into the question body. Also, lets us know if you solved the problem and, if you didn't solve the problem, please take into account that you can send an email to the `fiware-tech-help@lists.fiware.org` mail list.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your context broker instance doesn't support https notifications. You have to install Rush and configure your context broker for using it. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23338154/orion-context-broker-https-for-subscribers) for more info.

Take into account that the "NGSI Source" operator uses subscriptions while other widgets and operators use plain request (like queries) that works without needing https notifications.